# How to write NSIS code for form?

Tags: tabs, ms-office, nsis, portability

I using [Office Tab Portable](http://www.mediafire.com/?26h9ndtqgkdtvpu) made by Thinstall.com. And it have !)OfficeTabPortable.exe to active software. I wonder how to design template NSIS for !)OfficeTabPortable.exe file. I know it use "InstallOptions" plugin to make it. But I'm newbie in NSIS. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Both [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) and [InstallOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Contrib/InstallOptions/Readme.html) can be used to create custom pages.

They are part of the default install and example scripts are included, you should take a look at those...